# Eclipse, Maven, GWT & Restlet

Tags: java, gwt, maven, m2eclipse

I have a Maven project with two Maven modules - a Restlet API (com.letsjoin.api) and a GWT web client (com.letsjoin.web). Restlet allows for GWT serialization but the GWT client has to (as far as I know) have knowledge of the Restlet models.

However I cant see the API from the GWT client even though they are both part of the same eclipse project.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out - I needed to add a dependency between by GWT client and the restlet API in the GWT pom.xml.